# newbie-Example Plugins Location

Tags: gazebo-plugin, gazebo-tutorial, gazebo-1.9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

I am a Gazebo newbie. In the plugin tutorials, it is mentioned that the source code is available at  "gazebo_sources>/examples/plugins". Where do I find this? Is it supposed to be in my .gazebo folder? Or am I supposed to download it separately from somewhere?
Sorry for the basic question. I hope you can help me out.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4785/newbie-example-plugins-location/) by [tgkSUTD](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/538/tgksutd/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-10-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

They are in the gazebo src folders

if you just want to have look see here:

https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src

otherwise checkout the repo as described in the installation instructions...

---

Originally posted by [evilBiber](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/251/evilbiber/) with karma: 881 on 2013-10-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1